# Issues playing HLS on XBMC for Android

Tags: android, xbmc

Anyone would have a recomendation on how to improve HLS on Android when running XBMC

I read that native HLS on Android is pretty bad but no recomemnded solution on how to improve.
Not even sure XBMC uses the native HLS decoding

Its just impossible to watch a video..
Cache some of the video, plays, stops to cache, plays,....

Would really apreciate.

I use one of the Android Stick. It works great for everything except when videos are HLS..
(Also use XBMC on tablet, phone,..)

Comment: What is your problem? Add code too if you need help in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/) for Android to run HLS.

I use it and it works perfectly.

Comment: It also supports RTMP